# PIL saved jpeg string cannot be read in java

Tags: java, python, image, jpeg, python-imaging-library

I create a PIL image string on a python server:

```
frame = cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)
image = Image.fromstring('RGB', cv.GetSize(frame), frame.tostring(), 'raw', 'BGR')
buffer = cStringIO.stringIO()
image.save(buffer,'JPEG')
udptransmit(buffer.getvalue())
```

I have a java client trying to read the transmitted image string and reform the jpeg. This however doesn't seem to be working. I created a python client just to check, and I can reform the jpeg correctly using a call to pygame's load method.
The string being sent from python, contains characters 6:10 = JFIF, which is the correct format (also recognised by python's imghdr module.
In java, I ahve tried

1. simply writing the byte contents of the string received into a file and naming it with a .jpeg extension. The file isn't a valid jpeg.
2. Using `ImageIO` to read the bytes from the string. This produces a null image.
3. Tried to fetch `ImageReaderByFormat('JPEG')` and parse the bytes with this. This gives me an error stating '`Image is not a JPEG, starts with 0x...`'

I really can't see why python recognises the string as a valid jpeg and java doesn't. Do the two use different jpeg decoders? Even if they do, shouldn't both either validate or reject the string?

Comment: Perhaps you are having an endianness issue?

Comment: Are you using `wb` for the file writing mode?

Comment: Can't OpenCV do the JPEG encoding? Just seems like PIL is an unnecessary dependency.

Comment: well, I did try transmitting the frame from cv.captureFromCam() itself as a string, but, 1. it still didn't work and 2. the size was far far larger.
I'm not sure about opencv and jpeg encoding however

Comment: For the file writing, I used FileOutputStream, which doesn't take a wb or any other mode (as far as i know)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found a solution to the problem 
The problem was with the charset used in java while converting the string sent from my python server into bytes in java.
Here's the simple modification that was required in my java client code:

```
Charset charset = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1");
Byte[] bytes: Array[Byte] = cam_data.getBytes(charset)
File f = new File("image.jpeg")
FileImageOutputStream fios = new FileImageOutputStream(f)
BufferedImage  bim = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes))
ImageIO.write(bim,"jpeg",fios)
```

The helpful link that lead me to the answer was http://www.java-forums.org/advanced-java/50516-reading-image-files-into-strings.html